# What is the best way to interface with Stockfish in a C++ program?

Tags: software, stockfish

I am looking for a way to have my C++ program communicate with Stockfish. An ideal solution would use the compiled version and my program would send commands to the .exe which would return the results. I have looked extensively and have come across suggestions for pipes or the use of the system function but I am not sure how either of those work and if it's possible to have information returned to my C++ program. I am running on Windows. Any suggestions on what method to use and direction on how to apply that method would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code required for this is platform dependent, so it may be pragmatic to use a third party API to handle inter-process communication for you. Boost provides [`Boost.Process`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/process.html) and Qt provides `QtProcess`, both of which allow for communication via stdin and stdout.

Otherwise, you will have to directly interact with platform specific APIs, such as `CreateProcess` on Windows and `fork`, `pipe`, etc. on Linux.

Once you are able to communicate with the engine, you just need to follow the [UCI Protocol](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html) (which is used by Stockfish) to communicate with the engine.

Comment: Are these methods how most GUI interact with stockfish?

Comment: CuteChess, for example, uses the Windows API to interact with engines on windows and QtProcess on other operating systems.